# How to generate 20 characters alphanumeric unique id

Tags: php, hash

I want to generate 20 characters of hash code in php and insert in to table and the hash code should be unique.

And later the hash code can be used to access records in table.

```
<?php
   echo uniqid();
   //generate 20 charcter alphanumeric id here
?>
```

How can i do this?

Comment: https://github.com/ramsey/uuid - though why must it specifically be 20 characters? If you're imposing restrictions like that, what's the business justification to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this, it will always generate a different, unique string dependent on microtime and random number.

```
<?php
     // Here microtime will be unique everytime
     echo substr(md5(microtime()*rand(0,9999)),0,20);
 ?>
```

Comment: Picking substring of a unique number will not make the substring unique.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is wrong, you are cutting out the randomness with the `substr($random, 0, 20)` function call.

This would be better solution:

```
<?php
echo bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(10));
```

Also, it's bad idea to limit yourself to 20 characters if the string will be used only as the key in the DB. Why not use `uniqid($prefix, true)` instead.